# Orocos bfl for indigo,

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've tried including BFL into catkin using both

```
--   package 'orocos-bfl' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:283 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:337 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  navigation-indigo-devel/robot_pose_ekf/CMakeLists.txt:6 (pkg_check_modules)
```

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203209/orocos-bfl-for-indigo,/) by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2015-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just catkinized a package that I had been using a few years back, and I simply put `bfl` as a package and build dependency in my package.xml, and then I followed the directions on [Using BFL in ROS with Catkin Builds](http://wiki.ros.org/bfl) and everything compiled successfully.

To really help you debug your error, we'd need to see your package.xml and CMakeLists.txt. Although based on the experience I just described, and the first line of your error, it seems that something is referring to `orocos-bfl` instead of `bfl`.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zurish](https://answers.ros.org/users/20878/zurish/) on 2015-03-12**:
Hi there, I'm not sure where to add the lines in the second section of the link you provided .To the CMakeLists.txt who uses orocos-bfl? Or to orocos-bfl's CMakeLists.txt? Or somewhere else? Thank you.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-03-12**:
That would be the CMakeLists.txt in your ROS package.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you just trying to compile robot_pose_ekf? If so, try installing ros-indigo-bfl (sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-bfl) as you might be simply missing the dependency.

If you're trying to build your own package against BFL, check out the CMake in robot_pose_ekf: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/indigo-devel/robot_pose_ekf/CMakeLists.txt as it definitely builds against BFL in indigo, and as far as I know, it is the only released package that depends on BFL.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2015-03-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zurish](https://answers.ros.org/users/20878/zurish/) on 2015-03-13**:
I'm trying to install robot_pose_ekf to Mac OS. I can just clone it from gitbut and `catkin_make` it. Please see my question at [orocos-bfl](http://answers.ros.org/question/204942/orocos-bfl/). Thank you.